# openURL phone call with Guided Access ON

Tags: ios, openurl, guided-access

I have a simple contacts app that is intended to operate in Guided Access / Single App Mode. When the user hits the contact the app initiates a phone call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

Super simple and works fine with Guided Access off. I wonder if there is any way to make the phone call happen while guided access is on? I'm sure its likely a feature of guided access to not allow outgoing phone calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Guided Access keeps the iPhone in a single app, and allows you to
>   control which features are available. ...

From Guided Access's description I'm sure there is no normal way(maybe it's possible for jail-break iPhone, I'm not sure) to make phone call. Because phone call happens in another app. Apple will definitely forbid this.